# How to assemble, link, and compile combonation of C++, NASM files, and a .o driver

Tags: c++, assembly, compilation, linker, nasm

I have been having trouble trying to run my program that consists of a .cpp file that calls a bunch of 64bit NASM .asm files that call a .o driver file. I want to make a makefile for it but I can't figure out how to get it going in terminal to test it first. I am using a Linux system.

Update:
So I figured out some things.
Here is my current makefile, for some reason all it says is myclear.o is up to date.

```
ASM=nasm
LINK=g++
SOURCES=main.cpp

myclear.o:
    $(ASM) $< -f elf64 myclear.asm

mysetSize.o:
    $(ASM) $< -f elf64 mysetSize.asm

mypenUp.o:
    $(ASM) $< -f elf64 mypenUp.asm

mypenDown.o:
    $(ASM) $< -f elf64 mypenDown.asm

mysetDrawColor.o:
    $(ASM) $< -f elf64 mysetDrawColor.asm

mysetBkgndColor.o:
    $(ASM) $< -f elf64 mysetBkgndColor.asm

mymoveTo.o:
    $(ASM) $< -f elf64 mymoveTo.asm

draw: myclear.o mysetSize.o mypenUp.o mypenDown.o mysetDrawColor.o     mysetBkgndColor.o mymoveTo.o main.cpp
$(LINK) -Wall myclear.o mysetSize.o mypenUp.o mypenDown.o mysetDrawColor.o mysetBkgndColor.o mymoveTo.o main.cpp p1
```

Comment: Probably something like `nasm -f elf64 foo.asm && g++ bar.cpp foo.o driver.o`

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself
here is how my makefile looks, may not be very neat but it works, which is all I need.

```
LD=g++
ASM=nasm
LINK=g++
SOURCES=main.cpp
OBJ = $(SRC:.asm=.o)
OBJ2 = $(CPP:.cpp=.o)
CPP = main.cpp
SRC = myclear.asm mysetSize.asm mypenUp.asm mypenDown.asm mysetDrawColor.asm mysetBkgndColor.asm mymoveTo.asm

draw: myclear.o mysetSize.o mypenUp.o mypenDown.o mysetDrawColor.o mysetBkgndColor.o mymoveTo.o main.cpp plotterDriver.o
    $(LINK) -o draw myclear.o mysetSize.o mypenUp.o mypenDown.o mysetDrawColor.o mysetBkgndColor.o mymoveTo.o main.cpp plotterDriver.o

myclear.o:
    $(ASM) -f elf64 myclear.asm

mysetSize.o:
    $(ASM) -f elf64 mysetSize.asm

mypenUp.o:
    $(ASM) -f elf64 mypenUp.asm

mypenDown.o:
    $(ASM) -f elf64 mypenDown.asm

mysetDrawColor.o:
    $(ASM) -f elf64 mysetDrawColor.asm

mysetBkgndColor.o:
    $(ASM) -f elf64 mysetBkgndColor.asm

mymoveTo.o:
    $(ASM) -f elf64 mymoveTo.asm
```

Comment: Or make a pattern rule like `%.o: %.asm:` `$(ASM) -f elf64 $<`.  But yes, you go from source to `.o` with nasm or yasm, and then everything else is the same as always.